# How to build a ReferralUrl that works with sites that have a virtual directory and those that don't

Tags: java, jersey

I have a web service that uses Jersey.

For each request, I expect that the header will include an authentication token.

With that token, I need to initialize a UserSecurity object that will use that authentication token to load this users security settings from the database.

I then want this UserSecurity object to be visible in all my web service methods.

How would I go about doing this, does jersey have filters or something?

Answer (score 0):

jersey has filter. You can implement a containetRequestFilter to initialize your security object & put it to session